# Is there a way to identify whether a program has -ggdb provided as a gcc option?

Tags: c++, gcc, shared-libraries

In my C++ program I use two types of builds. One is the optimized build with no debug info (gcc -O3 ) and the other one is the optimized build with debug info (gcc -ggdb -O3 ). Inside my program I use dlopen ("library_name", RTLD*) to load some shared libraries. These shared libraries also have the same two builds.

Now my question is whether I can find inside my code whether the -ggdb option is included in the build so that I can do the following.

```
if (with_debug_info_build)//Need some way to identify whether -ggdb is provided
{
     void* h = dlopen("my_library.od.so", RTLD*);//Load library with debug info
}
else
{
      void* h = dlopen("my_library.so", RTLD*);//Load library without debug info
}
```

Truly appreciate your help on this. Thanks.

Comment: I think it would be better if you set `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` to point at the debug compiled library path when executing the debug compiled binary (or compile that into the binary). If you start making these checks in code, your debug builds will start diverging from the final binary. Note: You _could_ check `#ifdef NDEBUG` `/* release build */` `#else` `/* debug build */` `#endif`

Comment: Its a good option Ted. Even though optimized with debug info also define ndebug in my case, i can use a separate macro also. Thanks!

Comment: You're welcome! Note that I mentioned that as some you _could_ do, but I recommend _not_ doing it, but instead manage what libraries that gets loaded by providing a different environment for the binary via `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`. It will be a lot easier to maintain and will not clutter your code with `#ifdef`s.

Answer (score 0):

> In my C++ program I use two types of builds. One is the optimized build with no debug info (gcc -O3 ) and the other one is the optimized build with debug info (gcc -ggdb -O3 ).

Not a direct answer to your question, but above setup is generally the *wrong* approach to whatever problem it is trying to solve.

What you should do instead is have a *single* build with `-O3 -ggdb` which you use for development and debugging, and a way to copy the entire installation directory to a separate "release" directory and run `strip -g` on all the binaries in the "release" directory.

The binaries should load shared libraries from their corresponding installation tree (this is easy to achieve with e.g. `-Wl,-rpath='$ORIGIN/../lib'` if the binary is `${dir}/bin/exe` and you want it to use `${dir}/lib` for shared libraries).

Advantages:

- you can ship your release binaries anywhere you need to and still have access to exactly matching full debug info
- no mucking around with `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` -- "correct" library versions are loaded automagically

> Now my question is whether I can find inside my code whether the -ggdb option is included in the build?

Yes, you can. To do so, you would need to parse the executable file on disk, and determine whether it has debug info.

This is platform-specific. Assuming you have an ELF file, you can parse its section table, looking for sections named `.debug_info`, `.debug_line`, etc.). If you add `-frecord-gcc-switches` to your compile line, you may also read `.GCC.command.line` section to find the command line used, e.g.

```
gcc -g -O3 t.c -frecord-gcc-switches

readelf -x.GCC.command.line a.out

Hex dump of section '.GCC.command.line':
  0x00000000 2d696d75 6c746961 72636820 7838365f -imultiarch x86_
  0x00000010 36342d6c 696e7578 2d676e75 00742e63 64-linux-gnu.t.c
  0x00000020 002d6d74 756e653d 67656e65 72696300 .-mtune=generic.
  0x00000030 2d6d6172 63683d78 38362d36 34002d67 -march=x86-64.-g
  0x00000040 002d4f33 002d6672 65636f72 642d6763 .-O3.-frecord-gc
  0x00000050 632d7377 69746368 6573002d 66617379 c-switches.-fasy
  0x00000060 6e636872 6f6e6f75 732d756e 77696e64 nchronous-unwind
  0x00000070 2d746162 6c657300                   -tables.
```